# Maven module issue

Tags: java, maven, log4j2

Есть maven проект, в нем два модуля cleint, server. В главном pom.xml подключены все необходимые зависимости. Каждый модуль содержит log42.xml файл, в котором в пути написано сохранение логов в определенный файл. При компиляции проекта, выбрасывается ошибка.

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

Основной pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>by.runets</groupId>
  <artifactId>accountingSystem</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>accountingSystem</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <modules>
    <module>server</module>
    <module>client</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.10</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>8.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

</project>
```

pom.xml client module

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>accountingSystem</artifactId>
        <groupId>by.runets</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>client</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>client</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <compress>true</compress>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>a1s.client.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>by.runets.accountingsystem.main.MainApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

log42.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
       <File name="fileLog" fileName="log/logs.txt" append="true">
            <BurstFilter level = "debug"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] %c{2} - %m%n"/>
        </File>
        <Console name="consoleLog" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="consoleLog"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="fileLog"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Покажите как запускаете jar'ник. `-Dlog4j.configurationFile` точно правильный путь указывает?

Comment: @Suvitruf
запуск из ide

Comment: Структуру проекта покажите. Где у вас log42.xml лежит?

Comment: Кстати, файл должен называться **log4j2.xml**, а не **log42.xml**.

Comment: @Suvitruf файл называется log4j2.xml

Comment: @Suvitruf log4j2.xml лежит в src

Comment: Маленькое замечание :
<scope>compile</scope>
Это необязательно писать, потому что по умолчанию scope у зависимостей - compile.

Comment: В `src/main/resources` лежит?

Comment: @Suvitruf Чет лоханулся, файл лежал просто в src, положил в resources. Все заработало, спасибо!

Comment: @OfficialDev рад был помочь. Сделал ответом, чтоб и другим в будущем помогло.

Comment: @OfficialDev можете отметить его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**log4j2.xml** должен лежать в **src/main/resources**.